Not Able to install CA certificate on OnePlus 7 pro and Motorola device from Phone Settings
In My OnePlus 7 Pro and another Motorola phone when I am trying to install a CA certificate downloaded to phone storage in one-plus after clicking on install anyway fingerprint authentication screen appears and after the authentication Fils app which system opens to select the Certificate got crashed. I have another File manager but the system does not show any option to open another file manager app.
Crash log for OnePlus 7 Pro:
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask
                                                                                                           Process: com.google.android.documentsui, PID: 7386
                                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
                                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{f77357f 7386:com.google.android.documentsui/u0a357} (pid=7386, uid=10357) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
                                                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
                                                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
                                                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
                                                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
                                                                                                                at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:1229)
                                                                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:2671)
                                                                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:2659)
                                                                                                                at com.android.documentsui.roots.ProvidersCache.loadRootsForAuthority(ProvidersCache.java:330)
                                                                                                                at com.android.documentsui.roots.ProvidersCache.access$1400(ProvidersCache.java:81)
                                                                                                                at com.android.documentsui.roots.ProvidersCache$UpdateTask.handleDocumentsProvider(ProvidersCache.java:573)
                                                                                                                at com.android.documentsui.roots.ProvidersCache$UpdateTask.doInBackground(ProvidersCache.java:529)
                                                                                                                at com.android.documentsui.roots.ProvidersCache$UpdateTask.doInBackground(ProvidersCache.java:488)
                                                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
                                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
                                                                                                            Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
                                                                                                                at com.android.server.content.ContentService.registerContentObserver(ContentService.java:356)
                                                                                                                at android.content.IContentService$Stub.onTransact(IContentService.java:482)
                                                                                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1165)
                                                                                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1134)


For Motorola, the File App opened but only showed the recent folder opened (which is not actually a folder it's just a virtual location showing recently accessed files) but the downloaded certificate is in the download folder which does not appear in this recent folder.
I tried pushing the Certificate using adb but that is not allowed in Android 11 also tried using the application to trigger intent but it calls the same system installer which get calls when we click certificate from file explorer and shows error that this is not allowed you have to install it from settings
